# Set a value for DATA_CONVERTER_BATCH_SIZE -- not a valid id

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I am trying to **update my Magento 2.3 instance to 2.3.1**.

So I'm trying to finish the [update and upgrade checklist](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman-checklist.html#batch-size),

but when I get to the step:

`Set a value for DATA_CONVERTER_BATCH_SIZE`, I copied the command on the page `export DATA_CONVERTER_BATCH_SIZE 100000`

And I get the error

> bash: export: '100000': not a valid identifier

What should I do to fix this so I can update my installation?

Answer (score 4):

To set the variable on **Ubuntu**, enter the following command as the Magento file system owner in a bash shell prompt:

```
export DATA_CONVERTER_BATCH_SIZE=100000
```

output:
No output will be seen on screen, to see exported variable use below command.

```
 export | grep DATA_CONVERTER_BATCH_SIZE
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Thanks! I'll do this before I try to update again